# Need to remove package.json from ~ and have a clean terminal load

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

Goal is to open my terminal and only see my root folder.

Issue 1:

Whenever I open terminal I see this.

> npm ERR! path /Users/xxxx/package.json
>
> npm ERR! code ENOENT
>
> npm ERR! errno -2
>
> npm ERR! syscall open
>
> npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
>   '/Users/xxxxx/package.json'
>
> npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
>
> npm ERR! enoent
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>
> npm ERR!     /Users/xxxx/.npm/_logs/2019-03-15T01_59_32_671Z-debug.log

**Attempt to fix:**

> npm --version
>
> npm install express
>
> npm init -y

**Issue 2: Now when I open the terminal I see the messag**e

> xxxxxxxxx@1.0.0 test /Users/xxxxxxx
>
> echo "Error: no test specified" && exit 1 "mythical-creatures/test/unicorn-test.js#" "Aliases"
>
> Error: no test specified
>
> sh: line 0: exit: too many arguments
>
> npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details

***The mythical creature file is deep in my file system and I did use it not recently at some point.
Can anyone help?***

Comment: I recommend you looking into `~/.bashrc` and `~/.bash_profile` files (if they exist). There is some line that executes some npm scripts.

Comment: These files are executed every time you open terminal. You need to find npm related lines and remove them.